# jboss interceptor api 1.1 not found when added as sbt dependency

Tags: jboss, dependencies, sbt

I'm trying to set jboss-interceptor-api-1.1 as a dependency via sbt, but it can't be found. I've searched on Maven Repository and this version is there, can anyone help me?

Actually, I'm trying to use sbt-assembly. Removing the plugin dependency and adding the dependency to libraryDependencies still shows that error.

Stack trace:

```
[info] Resolving org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1 ...
[warn] problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom: invalid sha1: expected=453b712ff6cda3a3f10f46a9ab9b9a42fc9bc021 computed=56da14e5a3e7e5656fe2ed1942d9fc0c1f3b054b (122ms)
[warn]  module not found: org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/vicaba/.ivy2/local/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /Users/vicaba/.activator/repository/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   /Applications/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving javax.annotation#jsr250-api;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving javax.inject#javax.inject;1 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.sisu#org.eclipse.sisu.inject;0.3.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-annotations;1.5.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-classworlds;2.5.2 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.scala-logging#scala-logging_2.11;3.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.21 ...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.7 ...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:updateSbtClassifiers' for the full output.
[error] (*:updateSbtClassifiers) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1: not found
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Feb 1, 2017 9:51:26 AM
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, and am also using sbt-assembly, and am also using IntelliJ. Honestly, I think it's to do with IntelliJ, perhaps something in the latest update because SBT from the command line works fine.

Comment: Quick follow up: under the project's SBT settings I disabled "Download Sources for SBT and plugins", and was able to continue.

Comment: I'm another intellij user with this problem - disabling that option worked for me too

Comment: I also use intellij. @Seer suggestions worked for me as well.

Comment: To all those who are experiencing this, I suggest reporting to https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBINTER/

(I am not affected directly by it, because I don't use IntelliJ, but got alerted to this by someone else who uses my project in IntelliJ)

Comment: The issue tracking this in sbt-assembly is [#236](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/236)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

LCartwright is correct that this is due to the SHA-1 hash file differring from the hash of the POM on maven central.

To get around this you can add the JBoss maven repository, where [the hash](https://repository.jboss.org/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom.sha1) matches, to your resolvers in the [global sbt config](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html) ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt

```
resolvers += "JBoss" at "https://repository.jboss.org/"
```

Comment: I took the step of removing the extra resolver after the JBoss artifact had downloaded, as having unnecessary resolvers can be a dangerous thing: https://www.theguardian.com/info/developer-blog/live/2015/sep/21/conference-report-scala-world-2015?page=with:block-560180d8e4b0ae9eeb18805e#block-560180d8e4b0ae9eeb18805e

Comment: As suggested by Roberto, I removed the extra resolver afterwards; the compilation still worked, but with this warning: 
SBT project import
   [warn] problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom: invalid sha1: expected=453b712ff6cda3a3f10f46a9ab9b9a42fc9bc021 computed=56da14e5a3e7e5656fe2ed1942d9fc0c1f3b054b (100ms)

Comment: having the sha fixed is the only real solution:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBINTER-21

Answer (score 21):

I have the same issue in IntelliJ. When opening a project, it fails on jboss-interceptor-api. This is part of the log:

```bash
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-artifact;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.maven#maven-plugin-api;3.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.sisu#org.eclipse.sisu.plexus;0.0.0.M5 ...
[info] Resolving javax.enterprise#cdi-api;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1 ...
[warn] problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom: invalid sha1: expected=453b712ff6cda3a3f10f46a9ab9b9a42fc9bc021 computed=56da14e5a3e7e5656fe2ed1942d9fc0c1f3b054b (108ms)
[warn]  module not found: org.jboss.interceptor#jboss-interceptor-api;1.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jessedobbelaere/.ivy2/local/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom
[warn] ==== bintray-kamon-io-sbt-plugins: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/kamon-io/sbt-plugins/org.jboss.interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I noticed that when unchecking "Download Sources for SBT and plugins" in IntelliJ, everything works perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as a temporary fix. Do you have any idea of the root cause of this? I've just upgraded to IntelliJ 2016.3.4 from 2016.1 in which this wasn't a problem.

Comment: Unbelievable! IDEA has some great Scala features. But bugs like this make me wonder if it is worth it. (Still present in 2017.1 and the latest EAP)

Answer (score 11):

Seems like the culprit is this line

`[warn] problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom: invalid sha1: expected=453b712ff6cda3a3f10f46a9ab9b9a42fc9bc021 computed=56da14e5a3e7e5656fe2ed1942d9fc0c1f3b054b (108ms)`

reporting an incorrect SHA-1 for the pom file.

- pom: [jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom)
- pom SHA-1: [jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom.sha1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom.sha1)

The SHA-1 for the pom is `56da14e5a3e7e5656fe2ed1942d9fc0c1f3b054b` however the accompanying `pom.sha1` file is `453b712ff6cda3a3f10f46a9ab9b9a42fc9bc021`

As suggested above, unchecking "Download Sources for SBT and plugins" will solve your issue for now. Not sure who to contact to update the `pom.sha1`

Comment: Unchecking "Download Sources for SBT and plugins" - solved my issues after many hours of mucking around trying to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problems today and the plugin I used is `sbt-native-packager`. It also worked when I disable the option.

And later I go to the sbt github site and update my sbt plugin version from `1.0.0-RC1` to `1.2.0-M8` without disabling that option, I also worked. The plugin I used is

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.2.0-M8")
```

Maybe you can go to https://github.com/sbt to search the lastest version.